# apoc.load.json not in the list of procedures (neo4j 5.5, apoc 5.4), though other loaders are

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using neo4j 5.5 docker image with apoc 5.4 extended plugin, I do not have apoc.load.json in the list of available procedures, though other loaders (like load.html, load.jdbc, load.csv) are there and work fine. Did they remove load.json from the new version or am I doing something wrong? the apoc.help() procedure is also missing..

I have gone through the previous threads, the neo4j.conf settings seem to be correct, apoc.import.file.enabled set to "true", apoc plugin is in the right place (given that other apoc loaders work). The only one missing is the one I need for the project, json...
[available procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3QJv.png)

I added apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false, did not help..
Is there a way to add a procedure manually or something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using the APOC extended plugin, however, the function you are trying to use `apoc.load.json` is present in the APOC core. You need to add the APOC Core plugin to your database. Here are the links to the documentation:

[APOC Extended](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/#_apoc_load)

[APOC Core](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/overview/#_apoc_load)

Comment: there is no separate core edition for the latest apoc release: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases  

on their github page they say that core has been merged into extended: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/3276
Core versions from earlier releases do not work with neo4j 5, I tried apoc 4.4.

Comment: Sorry, correction: apoc core has been added to neo4j 5 package, but calling the procedure outputs  "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.load.json` registered for this database instance."

Comment: Make sure that the following setting is configured in `neo4j.conf` `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=jwt.security.*,apoc.*`

Comment: @foxly please check the comment above

Comment: @Charchit_Kapoor I have this setting in neo4j.conf, I also tested with and without dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.*, still same error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound

Do you have the same combo neo4j 5 + apoc 5?Does it work for you without problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just for the context: I had neo4j 4.3.15 and apoc 4.3.06 before, worked well, then I had to upgrade to neo4j 5. And since then I have not been able to make it work.

Comment: I haven't used neo4j docker image, but these are the most frequent errors, that I have encountered with APOC.

Comment: Meanwhile I installed neo4j 5 locally, same problem, so it does not come from the docker :(

Comment: That's strange.

Comment: Yes that is strange. It would be great if Neo4J people would listen to the problems that potential customers are struggling with. But that apparently is not the case. Better not using this product. Memgraph is open source and similar.